# Negation for \ze \zs in Vim

Tags: vim

In Vim,

`cat\zsdog` will match `dog` in `catdog`

`cat\zedog` will match `cat` in `catdog`

How can I use negation for `\zs` and `\ze`

For example, How can I match pattern `cat` not following by `dog`

And How can I match pattern `dog` not preceding by `cat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for `cat\(dog\)\@!`

Get help on this using

```
:help /\@!
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I never knew that:)